# python: fast and easy way to compare these lists?

Tags: python

I wrote a function for this, but I think its probably wildly inefficient and over-complicated so I wanted to ask if there was an easy way to do it.

Given two lists of lists...

```
foo = [['one', 1], ['two', 1], ['three', 1]]
bar = [['three', 1], ['four', 1], ['five', 1]]
```

I need a function that will return...

```
final = [['one', 1], ['two', 1], ['three', 2], ['four', 1], ['five', 1]]
```

so it checks if there is any overlaps of the first term, adds the second terms together and then returns a final list like above

EDIT:

foo/bar[1:] are guaranteed to be ordered, but they could be like this...

```
foo = [['the', 100], ['at', 99], ['for', 32]]
bar = [['mitochondria', 20], ['at', 10], ['you', 9]]
```

In other words, they would be relatively random words paired with descending numbers.

Comment: Are the lists `foo` and `bar` guaranteed to be in order themselves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> foo = [['one', 1], ['two', 1], ['three', 1]]
>>> bar = [['three', 1], ['four', 1], ['five', 1]]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(dict(foo)) + Counter(dict(bar))
Counter({'three': 2, 'four': 1, 'five': 1, 'two': 1, 'one': 1})
```

so

```
>>> (Counter(dict(foo)) + Counter(dict(bar))).items()
[('four', 1), ('five', 1), ('three', 2), ('two', 1), ('one', 1)]
```

if the order is important:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> counter = (Counter(dict(foo)) + Counter(dict(bar)))
>>> order = OrderedDict(foo + bar).keys()
>>> [[k, counter[k]] for k in order]
[['one', 1], ['two', 1], ['three', 2], ['four', 1], ['five', 1]]
```

If the items are gathered into a list `L`

```
>>> foo = [['one', 1], ['two', 1], ['three', 1]]
>>> bar = [['three', 1], ['four', 1], ['five', 1]]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> L = [foo, bar]
>>> counter = Counter()
>>> for item in L:
...     counter.update(dict(item))
... 
>>> order = OrderedDict(chain.from_iterable(L))
>>> [[k, counter[k]] for k in order]
[['one', 1], ['two', 1], ['three', 2], ['four', 1], ['five', 1]]
```

Comment: I did a quick stress test and I think this solution rocks, but i'm drawing a blank on how to do this with multiple **kwargs. You see I have a function that takes an amount of filenames in, reads them, splits them up and then combines the contents like this. How would you do that with a dynamic number of lists? I hope that makes sense

Comment: Doing `def myfunc(*args)`. when calling `args` you'll get a tuple of everything put in as an argument. You can then just turn this tuple into a list which can but used as describe.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you merely should concatenate the lists, sort the result, and run over it while counting repeated elements. Maybe `itertools.groupby` could help: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Answer (score 0):

```
f = [('one',2), ('two',3)]

g = [('one',2), ('three',4)]

print set(f) | set(g)

set([('three', 4), ('one', 2), ('two', 3)])
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

maybe more easier.
[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it should return ('one', 4) in the final output

Comment: it's impossible. it's the result of two sets union. It can't be ('one', 4)

Comment: it's not impossible John La Rooy's answer does it just fine

Answer (score 0):

You could use a default dictionary to do this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

foo = [['one', 1], ['two', 1], ['three', 1]]
bar = [['three', 1], ['four', 1], ['five', 1]]

mydict = defaultdict(int)

for each in foo+bar:
    mydict[each[0]]+=each[1]

foobar = [[x,y] for x,y in mydict.items()]
```

By using a default dictionary you insure that if the first value is not already in your dictionary you don't get a key error.

If your list maintain a predictable structure like you have posted you should be able to reliably index them when applying them to your dictionary.

This list comprehension at the bottom gives you back the structure that you started with

Comment: It's usual to use `int` instead of `lambda :0`

Comment: Got it. Changed it to the natural nomenclature. Thanks.

Comment: I did misunderstood and did `defaultdict(lambda: int)` instead of just `defaultdict(int)` which I realized after further consideration.

Comment: Ah.. that makes sense